# scons and virtualenv import issue

Tags: python, virtualenv, scons

I have been working with an ubuntu 12.04 for a long time and I use scons to compile my code. I am also using `virtualenv` (and `virtualenvwrapper`).

Today I tried ubuntu 14.04 on a VM (future here I come :) ).

When I run scons (inside the virtualenv) it failed because he can't find a certain package (psutil but it doesn't really matter which one). I was confused because I `pip installed -r requirements.txt` and I know psutil is there.

To be sure I tried `pip freeze | grep psutil` and I saw it there.
After a short research I found out that the scons version on 14.04 is newer than the one I have on my 12.04. (2.3.0 and 2.1.0 respectively).

I tried to understand what can cause to such thing to happen and I saw that the older scons uses `#! /usr/bin/env python` while the new scons uses `#! /usr/bin/python`. Since I have not installed psutil on my system python scons fails.

Is there a better approach than modify the new scons to use `#! /usr/bin/env python`?

Comment: Actually `/usr/bin/env` python will provide you access on `/usr/bin/python`. It's better to use `env` because if a day your python address doesn't be in `/usr/bin/python` , `env` will find it for you and your code can run on all distributions.

Comment: @Mortezaipo So why do you think scons guys use `/usr/bin/python` in the first place?

Comment: I suspect that default Python version you've got for ubunut 14.04 is python 3 (check it out with `/usr/bin/env python --version`). But `scons` is still for python 2 only. Are you sure you have no conflicts with python versions in your `virtualenv`? Have you specified python version when created `virtualenv`? It's done with `virtualenv --python=/path/to/python`. Also, have you upgraded your pip?

Comment: @AndyThomas I've checked the last version (2.4.1). `scons` in bin directory uses `env`.

Comment: @Mortezaipo Where do you look? I removed scons and installed it using apt-get and it still uses `/usr/bin/python/`. Do you know where can I find this file in their repo?

Comment: @AndyThomas all `apt-get` packages are not latest version. try it via `pip` or `easy_install`. I've downloaded that directly via its official website: http://www.scons.org/download.php

Comment: Also you should know that most distributions make changes to packages they distribute. It could be the /usr/bin/env vs /usr/bin/python is something that ubuntu/debian changed for their package..